# Log files big size

Tags: linux, logs, services

I have log files for different services, those log files are taking up too much disk space, when I tried to truncate one of them with `>run.log` the file is truncated, but after some hours it got big again very quickly. I tried also `rm -f` but the files disappear and still occupying the space.

Has anybody have any solution for this? It is driving me crazy.

Comment: Fight the cause, not the symptom: Find out what is messing up the log files; it's probably indicating a problem that should be solved (log files are not meant to drive you crazy, but to log relevant system events). If it's something you don't care about, the messages can  probably be configured not to be logged. And finally, don't manually empty log files, but use `logrotate`

Comment: @Philippos is right.  You should also check if some service is set to log debug-messages.  Websphere-Servers log an insane amount of messages, when their logging is set to "finest"...

Comment: @Philippos For some log files, such as `mail.log`, it just gets huge and everything being logged should be logged. The fixes include, as suggested below, to rotate more frequently and compress rotations, or move the noisier log elements to a separate file (and rotate that one).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you set up `logrotate` for the logfiles in question.
The manpage has a few examples, and you will find configuration files you can copy-paste from in `/etc/logrotate.d`

Something like this, maybe. But that depends on how many files you need to keep...

```
/var/log/tooobig
{
    rotate 7
    daily
    copytruncate
    missingok
    notifempty
    delaycompress
    compress
}
```

If you put the above in a file in `/etc/logrotate.d/`...

- `daily` the file will be rotated daily...
- `rotate 7`  seven files will be kept ( tooobig, tooobig.1, ... tooobig.6.gz)
- `compress` you guessed it, the files will be compressed
- `delaycompress` tooobig.1 will not be compressed, but the following ones will be
- `missingok` don't throw errors if the file is missing
- `notifempty` do not rotate empty files.
- `copytruncate` Truncate  the original log file to zero size in place after creating a copy. Some programs need that.  see `man logrotate`

Comment: until now the solution I found , is that I delete the log and restart the service , but this can't be done every time because for example Mongodb I can't restart it every time I delete the file specially I'm in Production environment

Comment: One more reason to use logrotate.  No restarts required.

Comment: it's new for me this hhh , I just learned how to do a cron job , so to learn something else :/

Comment: If you are interested in system-administration, I suggest you pick up a book or two for the LPIC-1 and LPIC-2 Certifications AND a good textbook on Linux.  That will save you a lot of time.  I'm speaking from experience here :-)  I spend lots of time reading manuals and googling stuff on my job...

Comment: okey thank you so much